# Database SQLite cannot created?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, parsing

This is continued from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486452/how-to-parse-xml-file-from-http-into-sqlite-in-android/). I've made code for database, but when I run my apps it won't create database. I don't know where I got wrong, but in eclipse my code don't show any error. Here my code from my apps.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
static final String URL = "http://data.bmkg.go.id/propinsi_15_2.xml";
static final String KEY_ITEM = "Cuaca";
static final String KEY_ID = "Isi";
static final String KEY_ROW = "Row";
static final String KEY_KOTA = "Kota";
static final String KEY_LINTANG = "Lintang";
static final String KEY_BUJUR = "Bujur";
static final String KEY_CUACA = "Cuaca";
static final String KEY_SUHUMIN = "SuhuMin";
static final String KEY_SUHUMAX = "SuhuMax";
static final String KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN = "KelembapanMin";
static final String KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX = "KelembapanMax";
static final String KEY_KECEPATANANGIN = "KecepatanAngin";
static final String KEY_ARAHANGIN = "ArahAngin";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new AmbilData().execute();

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
}

class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading, Mohon Menunggu Beberapa saat...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground (String... args){
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ROW);
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            map.put(KEY_KOTA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_KOTA));
            map.put(KEY_LINTANG, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINTANG));
            map.put(KEY_BUJUR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BUJUR));
            map.put(KEY_CUACA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CUACA));
            map.put(KEY_SUHUMIN, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUHUMIN));
            map.put(KEY_SUHUMAX, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUHUMAX));
            map.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN, parser.getValue(e, KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN));
            map.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX, parser.getValue(e, KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX));
            map.put(KEY_KECEPATANANGIN, parser.getValue(e, KEY_KECEPATANANGIN));
            map.put(KEY_ARAHANGIN, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARAHANGIN));

            menuItems.add(map);
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, menuItems, R.layout.list_kota, new String[] {KEY_KOTA, KEY_CUACA, KEY_LINTANG, KEY_BUJUR, KEY_SUHUMIN, KEY_SUHUMAX, KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN, KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX, KEY_KECEPATANANGIN, KEY_ARAHANGIN}, new int[] {R.id.kota, R.id.cuaca, R.id.lintang, R.id.bujur, R.id.suhumin, R.id.suhumax, R.id.kelembapanmin, R.id.kelembapanmax, R.id.kecepatanangin, R.id.arahangin});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**KabupatenList.java**

```
public class KabupatenList {
// private variables
int _Row;
String _Kota;
String _Lintang;
String _Bujur;
String _Cuaca;
String _SuhuMin;
String _SuhuMax;
String _KelembapanMin;
String _KelembapanMax;
String _KecepatanAngin;
String _ArahAngin;

// Empty constructor
public KabupatenList() {

}

// constructor
public KabupatenList(int Row, String Kota, String Lintang, String Bujur,
        String Cuaca, String SuhuMin, String SuhuMax, String KelembapanMin,
        String KelembapanMax, String KecepatanAngin, String ArahAngin) {
    this._Row = Row;
    this._Kota = Kota;
    this._Lintang = Lintang;
    this._Bujur = Bujur;
    this._Cuaca = Cuaca;
    this._SuhuMin = SuhuMin;
    this._SuhuMax = SuhuMax;
    this._KelembapanMin = KelembapanMin;
    this._KelembapanMax = KelembapanMax;
    this._KecepatanAngin = KecepatanAngin;
    this._ArahAngin = ArahAngin;
}

// constructor
public KabupatenList(String Kota, String Lintang, String Bujur,
        String Cuaca, String SuhuMin, String SuhuMax, String KelembapanMin,
        String KelembapanMax, String KecepatanAngin, String ArahAngin) {
    this._Kota = Kota;
    this._Lintang = Lintang;
    this._Bujur = Bujur;
    this._Cuaca = Cuaca;
    this._SuhuMin = SuhuMin;
    this._SuhuMax = SuhuMax;
    this._KelembapanMin = KelembapanMin;
    this._KelembapanMax = KelembapanMax;
    this._KecepatanAngin = KecepatanAngin;
    this._ArahAngin = ArahAngin;
}

// getting row
public int getRow() {
    return this._Row;
}

// setting row
public void setRow(int Row) {
    this._Row = Row;
}

// getting kota
public String getKota() {
    return this._Kota;
}

// setting kota
public void setKota(String Kota) {
    this._Kota = Kota;
}

// getting lintang
public String getLintang() {
    return this._Lintang;
}

// setting lintang
public void setLintang(String Lintang) {
    this._Lintang = Lintang;
}

// getting bujur
public String getBujur() {
    return this._Bujur;
}

// setting bujur
public void setBujur(String Bujur) {
    this._Bujur = Bujur;
}

// getting cuaca
public String getCuaca() {
    return this._Cuaca;
}

// setting cuaca
public void setCuaca(String Cuaca) {
    this._Cuaca = Cuaca;
}

// getting suhumin
public String getSuhuMin() {
    return this._SuhuMin;
}

// setting suhumin
public void setSuhuMin(String SuhuMin) {
    this._SuhuMin = SuhuMin;
}

// getting suhumax
public String getSuhuMax() {
    return this._SuhuMax;
}

// setting suhumax
public void setSuhuMax(String SuhuMax) {
    this._SuhuMax = SuhuMax;
}

// getting kelembapanmin
public String getKelembapanMin() {
    return this._KelembapanMin;
}

// setting kelembapanmin
public void setKelembapanMin(String KelembapanMin) {
    this._KelembapanMin = KelembapanMin;
}

// getting kelembapanmax
public String getKelembapanMax() {
    return this._KelembapanMax;
}

// setting kelembapanmax
public void setKelembapanMax(String KelembapanMax) {
    this._KelembapanMax = KelembapanMax;
}

// getting kecepatan angin
public String getKecepatanAngin() {
    return this._KecepatanAngin;
}

// setting kecepatan angin
public void setKecepatanAngin(String KecepatanAngin) {
    this._KecepatanAngin = KecepatanAngin;
}

// getting arah angin
public String getArahAngin() {
    return this._ArahAngin;
}

// setting arah angin
public void setArahAngin(String ArahAngin) {
    this._ArahAngin = ArahAngin;
}
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbKabupaten";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_KABUPATEN = "tbKabupaten";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ROW = "Row";
private static final String KEY_KOTA = "Kota";
private static final String KEY_LINTANG = "Lintang";
private static final String KEY_BUJUR = "Bujur";
private static final String KEY_CUACA = "Cuaca";
private static final String KEY_SUHUMIN = "SuhuMin";
private static final String KEY_SUHUMAX = "SuhuMax";
private static final String KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN = "KelembapanMin";
private static final String KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX = "KelembapanMax";
private static final String KEY_KECEPATANANGIN = "KecepatanAngin";
private static final String KEY_ARAHANGIN = "ArahAngin";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_KABUPATEN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_KABUPATEN + "("
            + KEY_ROW + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_KOTA + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LINTANG + " TEXT" + KEY_BUJUR + " TEXT" + KEY_CUACA + " TEXT" + KEY_SUHUMIN + " TEXT" + KEY_SUHUMAX + " TEXT" + KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN + " TEXT" + KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX + " TEXT" + KEY_KECEPATANANGIN + " TEXT" + KEY_ARAHANGIN + " TEXT" +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_KABUPATEN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_KABUPATEN);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addKabupatenList(KabupatenList kabupatenList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_KOTA, kabupatenList.getKota()); // Kota
    values.put(KEY_LINTANG, kabupatenList.getLintang()); // Lintang
    values.put(KEY_BUJUR, kabupatenList.getBujur()); //Bujur
    values.put(KEY_CUACA, kabupatenList.getCuaca()); //Cuaca
    values.put(KEY_SUHUMIN, kabupatenList.getSuhuMin()); //SuhuMin
    values.put(KEY_SUHUMAX, kabupatenList.getSuhuMax()); //SuhuMax
    values.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN, kabupatenList.getKelembapanMin()); //KelembapanMin
    values.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX, kabupatenList.getKelembapanMax()); //KelembapanMax
    values.put(KEY_KECEPATANANGIN, kabupatenList.getKecepatanAngin()); //KecepatanAngin
    values.put(KEY_ARAHANGIN, kabupatenList.getArahAngin()); //ArahAngin


    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_KABUPATEN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
KabupatenList getKabupatenList(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_KABUPATEN, new String[] { KEY_ROW,
            KEY_KOTA, KEY_LINTANG, KEY_BUJUR, KEY_CUACA, KEY_SUHUMIN, KEY_SUHUMAX, KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN, KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX, KEY_KECEPATANANGIN, KEY_ARAHANGIN }, KEY_ARAHANGIN + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    KabupatenList kabupatenList = new KabupatenList();
    // return contact
    return kabupatenList;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<KabupatenList> getKabupaten() {
    List<KabupatenList> kabupaten = new ArrayList<KabupatenList>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_KABUPATEN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            KabupatenList kabupatenList = new KabupatenList();
            kabupatenList.setRow(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            kabupatenList.setKota(cursor.getString(1));
            kabupatenList.setLintang(cursor.getString(2));
            kabupatenList.setBujur(cursor.getString(3));
            kabupatenList.setCuaca(cursor.getString(4));
            kabupatenList.setKelembapanMin(cursor.getString(5));
            kabupatenList.setKelembapanMax(cursor.getString(6));
            kabupatenList.setKecepatanAngin(cursor.getString(7));
            kabupatenList.setArahAngin(cursor.getString(8));
            // Adding contact to list
            kabupaten.add(kabupatenList);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return kabupaten;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateKabupaten(KabupatenList kabupatenList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_KOTA, kabupatenList.getKota());
    values.put(KEY_LINTANG, kabupatenList.getLintang());
    values.put(KEY_BUJUR, kabupatenList.getBujur());
    values.put(KEY_CUACA, kabupatenList.getCuaca());
    values.put(KEY_SUHUMIN, kabupatenList.getSuhuMin());
    values.put(KEY_SUHUMAX, kabupatenList.getSuhuMax());
    values.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN, kabupatenList.getKelembapanMin());
    values.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX, kabupatenList.getKelembapanMax());
    values.put(KEY_KECEPATANANGIN, kabupatenList.getKecepatanAngin());
    values.put(KEY_ARAHANGIN, kabupatenList.getArahAngin());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_KABUPATEN, values, KEY_ROW + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(kabupatenList.getRow()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteKabupaten(KabupatenList kabupatenList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_KABUPATEN, KEY_ROW + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(kabupatenList.getRow()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getKabupatenCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_KABUPATEN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

What should I do to make apps can parsing xml and store to SQLite. Is there something wrong with my code or should I make change into my code?

Comment: Placing this much amount of code won't help you solving the problem. Post piece of code that is relavent

Comment: ya you should be add such a code where you get stuff.

Comment: Sorry for my bad, I'm new in programming so I don't have confident to post piece of code because I worried if everyone don't understand what I want

Answer (score 0):

You're create statement is missing commas. You current have

```
String CREATE_KABUPATEN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_KABUPATEN + "("
        + KEY_ROW + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_KOTA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_LINTANG + " TEXT" + KEY_BUJUR + " TEXT" + KEY_CUACA + " TEXT" + KEY_SUHUMIN + " TEXT" + KEY_SUHUMAX + " TEXT" + KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN + " TEXT" + KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX + " TEXT" + KEY_KECEPATANANGIN + " TEXT" + KEY_ARAHANGIN + " TEXT" +")";
```

It should be

```
String CREATE_KABUPATEN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_KABUPATEN + "("
        + KEY_ROW + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_KOTA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_LINTANG + " TEXT, " + KEY_BUJUR + " TEXT, " + KEY_CUACA + " TEXT, " + KEY_SUHUMIN + " TEXT, " + KEY_SUHUMAX + " TEXT, " + KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN + " TEXT, " + KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX + " TEXT, " + KEY_KECEPATANANGIN + " TEXT, " + KEY_ARAHANGIN + " TEXT" +")";
```